# Openssl: Do the RSA_verify() and X509_verify_cert() uses common RSA verification code

Tags: c, linux, openssl

Do the [RSA_verify()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rsa_verify) and  [X509_verify_cert()](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/X509_verify_cert.html) uses any common RSA signature verification code ? (I mean the signature verification part only).

I went through the openssl source code and could not figure it out. The X509_verify_cert() seems to use ASN1_verify() at the end, and the RSA_verify() doesn't seem to use it.

Some valuable comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atlast I found it. X509_verify_cert  make use of  RSA_verify